# Access JSON index keys returned from laravel with groupBy() function

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5.6

How can I access the first object in json response?

In controller:

```
Model::with('some_relation')->get()->groupBy('id');
return response()->json(['transactions' => $transactions]);
```

In view I get with ajax the json response:
e.g.
data:

```
  {
    72: [{...},{...},{...}],
    75: [{...},{...}],
    80: [{...},{...},{...},{...}]
    }
```

Now, if I want to access the first object (`72`) in jquery,  I can't access it using `data[0]` to get the first array. I have to access it like `data[72]`.
The data will be variable so I don't know what the id will be.

How can I access the first object?

Comment: You want to reference the array that is referenced by key `72`?  If so that would be `Object.values(data)[0]`

Comment: Ah nice that works :))). Spent 2 hours on it couldn't figure it out :((. If you post it as an answer I will vote it correct. Thank you.

Comment: If I want to loop through the arrays with ` $.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {}` when I want to access the i in a if something like: if (i === 0) {} I have the same problem as the i is either 72,75 or 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want them grouped, and not associated by the id, then reindex the collection with values().  Associative arrays don't exist in Javascript.

This will organize it into a JSON array instead of a JSON object.

```
Model::with('some_relation')->get()->groupBy('id')->values();
```